# Covariance error on Valued Type interface

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, covariance, value-type

I have a generic interface holding a covariant TValue parameter and an abstract class that does some repetitive stuff to liberate the child classes from that burden. Then I have 2 subclasses that extend from that abstract one, the first setting the generic parameter as a string and the second as an int.

This is a subpiece of code taken from the project, overly simplified just to focus on the matter.

```
public interface IElement<out TValue>
{
    string Name { get; }
    TValue Value { get; }
}

public abstract class Element<TValue> : IElement<TValue>
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    public Element(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Name : Element<string>
{
    public Name() : base("Name") { }
}

public class Height : Element<int>
{
    public Height() : base("Height") { }
}
```

Basically - and this is not what I'm doing in my code, but illustrates fairly simply the problem I'm having - if I try to assign Name to an IElement holding object like this:

```
IElement<object> element = new Name();
```

It succeeds as I had expected since the TValue parameter in IElement is covariant.
However if I set it to Height:

```
IElement<object> element = new Height();
```

I get an `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Height' to 'IElement<object>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` error.

Now, I don't know why this works with a class that sets the generic parameter as a string, but not with a an int (or enum as I have also in the project some enums). Is it because string is a class and int is a struct?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, because one is a *value type*. The CLR disallows it as it will need to preserve its identity, whereas boxing does not.

[Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) has a great blog about this at [Representation and identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/)

> covariant and contravariant conversions of interface and delegate
>   types require that all varying type arguments be of reference types.
>   To ensure that a variant reference conversion is always
>   identity-preserving, all of the conversions involving type arguments
>   must also be identity-preserving. The easiest way to ensure that all
>   the non-trivial conversions on type arguments are identity-preserving
>   is to restrict them to be reference conversions.

Additionally, you can read a lot more about identity, conversion, generics and variance in the specs at various places

**11.2.11 Implicit conversions involving type parameters**

> For a type-parameter T that is not known to be a reference type
>   (§15.2.5), the following conversions involving T are considered to be
>   boxing conversions (11.2.8) at compile-time. At run-time, if T is a
>   value type, the conversion is executed as a boxing conversion. At
>   run-time, if T is a reference type, the conversion is executed as an
>   implicit reference conversion or identity conversion.

Comment: It appears I still have a lot to study. Although I understand your explanation there are still a lot of concepts in it that I do not compreend totally. Thanks for putting me on the right track!